# When importing data into Excel via web query, how do I convert a column from 'text' to 'number'?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a web query that I am using to import a report into an excel workbook.
I cannot edit the data types of the fields in the original report.

There is one column that contains integers, but is being seen as text in the import.

I can obviously manually fix this, but the report runs automatically and I want users to be able to refresh the web query and not have to change the type of that column every time.

Is there some way that I can change the data type of the column on the import and it gets converted every time I refresh?

Comment: You could use VBA to do this but in native Excel I don't think so, maybe other SuperUsers can prove me wrong? Are you sure in the source table the format is int?

Comment: No I am not sure. The source file is XML and I cannot control what it looks like in any way.

Comment: You'll probably want to use VBA then, try this, let me know if you need help with the code & I'll post an answer http://www.excelandaccess.com/create-beforeafter-query-update-events/

Comment: Select a blank cell.  `Copy`.  Select the cells to change to numbers.  `Paste Special ► Add`.  This will change the column format to `General`, and also change the values to `Numbers`.

Comment: If you want to avoid VBA, or any extra actions by your users, you could have them paste into a different range and then have formulae in your report range that just copy the data, using `=VALUE(cell_in_other_range)` where you need to convert it

Comment: have you tried [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) function (from Excel 2016). XML-File as data source is available.

Answer (score 0):

focusing on :

> ..being seen as text in the import.

I normally just let the 'imported' data lands on one sheet/file[1], then use another sheet/file[2] to do `=value(A1)`. Then link the output cell/sheet/file to the [2] one rather than the original [1]. You may also consider `=text()` function if needed.

Hope it helps. (: